# Calling Javascript function from handlebar

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

How can I call a JavaScript function from inside a handlebars script?
Reason:

I wasn't able to break the `{{#each}}` from inside handlebars. So I need to pass it to JavaScript to do the logic.

Comment: Can you provide a simple code snippet?

Comment: I take it you are using a helper method?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can do that with helpers;

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("printItems", function(items) {
  var html = "<ul>";
  items.forEach(function(entry) {
    html += "<li>" + entry + "</li>";
  });
  html += "</ul>";
  return html;
});
```

and in your handlebars template;

```
{{printItems items}}
```

Above code will put your items in list.

For more details refer [here](http://handlebarsjs.com/). Go to helpers section

Answer (score 7):

Handlebars is a minimal tempting language for JavaScript and as such it will not let you execute arbitrary code from within a template. Handlebars does however provide you with helpers let you execute pre-defined code over your template. The built in ones are: `each`, `unless`, `if` and `else`.

You can create your own helpers with the `Handlebars.registerHelper` method. Here is a simple example that formats a phone number. So long as you register the helper before you call it you should be able to use `{{formatPhoneNumber phoneNumber}}` anywhere in your code.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("formatPhoneNumber", function(phoneNumber) {
  phoneNumber = phoneNumber.toString();
  return "(" + phoneNumber.substr(0,3) + ") " + 
    phoneNumber.substr(3,3) + "-" + 
    phoneNumber.substr(6,4);
});
```

Note: While it may be technically possible to execute non-rendering code from within a helper, this is considered bad practice and should be avoided if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with manupulations of data in handlebars template you need to add the helper and call that helper in the template.

Read more here...

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers