# Format Date With JS Function In HTML td

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I am attempting to display the date from a MySQL table as MM/DD/YYYY in my HTML. To do this, I have built a function in my script.js file:

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [month, day, year].join('/');
}
```

I am trying to call the JS function from my handlebars file and I am getting an error in the console saying:

```
   Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
 <td><script>formatDate(Sat May 05 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC));</script></td>
```

After doing some searching it seems like maybe the issue is with some of the special characters being passed into the function. The field in the database is of type `date` not `datetime` so I'm not even sure why there are any characters at all after the year. I am calling the function like this:

```
  {{#each results}}
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{this.id}}">
        <td>{{this.recipient_fname}}</td>
        <td>{{this.recipient_lname}}</td>
        <td>{{this.email}}</td>
        <td><script>formatDate({{this.date}})</script></td>
      <td>{{this.type}}</td>
      <td>{{this.region}}</td>
      <td>{{this.created_by}}</td>
    </tr>

  {{/each}}

</table>
{{/if}}

<button onclick="exportTableToCSV('awards.csv')">Export To CSV File</button>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Is there something I am missing with regards to calling a function in HTML? Or is there a better way to do this that I have missed?

Comment: Try removing the `{{}}` braces or wrap quotes around them

Comment: @charlietfl I tried both of those and it gets me closer. The console now says that formatDate is not defined even though I have it defined in my script.js file. I tried this too `
    <td><script src="script.js">formatDate(this.date)</script></td>` but nothing displayed in the column.

Comment: Put that function inside `script.js`. A script tag that has an `src` can't also have raw code inside it...it's either/or

Comment: @charlietfl this is what I have right now `<td><script>formatDate(this.date)</script></td>` and `formatDate()` is in `script.js`

Comment: Probably should be `<td>{{formatDate(this.date)}}</td>` (no script tag). I haven't used handlebars for quite a few years

Comment: You should use handle bar helpers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845710/calling-javascript-function-from-handlebar